# Delete by Object Id angular 2 and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, angular

I am trying to delete Posts from a comments section in my web app. Mongodb passes an objectId but I am unable to get it from my angular 2 front end. By default ObjectId is passed as `_id` so on my front end I call `Post._id` in my delete function and it passes through all this info

[image]

what I actually want is the unique ObjectId given by the database itself that look like this

[image]

How can I get this value on the front end of my application? I have all the code to my project on github located [here](https://github.com/bcrawford11/Angular2-w-CRUD-Api-MongoDb) with both my UI and API backend. Thanks for any help!

**relative files from repo**

- UI/src/app/components - PostData.Service.ts
- UI/src/app/components -postRand.component.ts
- UI/src/app/components/models - Post.ts
- API/src/controllers - PostAPIController.cs
- API/src/models - Post.cs
- API/src/models - DataAccess.cs

**API Running**

[image]

I believe I need to make this fix in the api layer because it is passing my `_id` as an object and not a string... This is just a guess of mine and I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. The problem is that `ObjectId` gets serialized as an object and not a string?

Comment: I believe that is whats going on...

Comment: Where in your code do you pass the mongo object from the backend to the front end ?

Comment: Yes, I know, but the repo is huge, hence the question.

Comment: I updated the question with the relevant file names as well as where in the repo to find them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to solve my issue....

1. I had to go back into my model and convert my ObjectId to a string by parsing it out

   `[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
       public string Id
       {
           get { return Convert.ToString(_id); }
           set { _id = MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId.Parse(value); }
       }`
2. I then added my new Id field to all of my http calls changing out where I was calling by ObjectId, to now call upon my new string value Id
3. Now when I run my Api get the actual Id of my object [image]
4. Lastly I added my newly generated Id field to my front end, replacing the old objectId value in my delete functions with the new Id.

All code has been updated in my git project, see file referenced in question for relevant documents.

Answer (score 0):

After review it looks like you are trying to delete the object by an object id string instead of an object id object.

In PostAPIController.cs

line 74

objds.Remove(post._id);

This is looking for an object with a string value to match on.

Pretty sure it should be like this

objds.Remove(ObjectId.Parse(post._id))

This will construct a object id to match on for the deletion

Comment: it wont allow that because its trying to convert an ObjectId into a string. I feel that I need to some how take the object from my Post.cs and convert it into a string there?